# Liking a Facebook page from native iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I am attempting to LIKE a business Facebook Like page (facebook.com/[LikePage]) from my native iOS application. I have used FB iOS SDK for login/logout purpose.

I have implemented the LIKE button similar to http://angelolloqui.com/blog/10-Facebook-Like-Button-on-iOS, which is an implementation of the social plugin on a webview. I did so, because of my understanding that to implement a custom LIKE button, I need to use the Built-in Like provided by FB which in turn would require that my actions be approved by FB.

However, it was brought to my notice that the social plugin implementation cannot be used in an iOS native application and can be used only in a mobile web app. 
So, here are my questions :-

1. Is it true that native iOS applications cannot use the social plugin provided by facebook to like a Facebook Page ?
2. Is it true that in order to build a custom Like button and not the plugin, I need to use the Built-in Likes provided by Facebook, which in turn would require approval of my action types ? (In my case, LIKE a Page)
   All I need is some concrete documentation which clearly lets me know which is the best way forward.
   FYI, the business page URL's that need to be LIKEd, come dynamically from server.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no API or automatic method to like facebook pages. The built-in open graph action, once approved, allows you to like other URLs which have Open Graph meta tags on them but not Facebook Pages.

The Like button plugin should work in a webview as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for that. So, is it confirmed that I cannot LIKE a Facebook Page using the Built-in Like action ?   I am still unable to see anything like this in the documentation. However, when I tried doing so using the Graph API explorer tool, it returned "Like doesnot support this kind of object" or something like.

Comment: It's mentioned briefly on the [Built-in like document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/) - "For Facebook Pages or websites that do not integrate with Facebook Authentication, developers should continue to use the Like button social plugin.'

Comment: So, how do you come to know if a page is integrated with Facebook Authentication ? As I have said earlier, these pages come dynamically to my app from the server.

Comment: You don't, but if you're planning on publishing likes against objects, you presumably already know what those objects are - if not, you could try accessing the URL via the API and see if it has an ID?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a regular [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to like the page, or use another library to make a post call to: `https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_OR_OBJECT_ID}/likes`. Make sure you add the [acces_token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) as a parameter.

I use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to post requests:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/likes", myObjectID];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"access_token" : FBSession.activeSession.accessToken};

[httpClient postPath:link parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id result) {

    NSLog(@"result %@", result);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"error %@", error);

}];
```

Comment: this did not work for me. Getting insufficient_scope error: (#200) "App does not have permission to make this call". My pub permissions are: publish_actions, publish_stream, user_likes. What do your permissions look like?

Answer (score 1):

An update to this post:-

"With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, the Like Button for iOS is deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/like-button

Comment: Bummer. Does anyone know of another method to accomplish this? I was using it to drive FB Page likes for my app.

Comment: I am redirecting user to either the app or browser page, where he/she can like or do anything with the page (may have to login if not already). When user come back to my application, I just use the graph APIs to check if the page is liked or not.

Comment: The above link won't work as the doc has been updated and moved.

Answer (score 0):

try this Code:

I think this will surely help you:

Fb like Widget can be embedded in our application. You just have to add a webView and get the [Fb Like Widget html code/URL here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/).

in ViewController.h where you want to add fb like button:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView * fbLikeWebView;

-(void)embedFBLikeButton;

@end
```

in TestViewController.m

```
#import "AboutUsViewController.h"

@implementation AboutUsViewController

@synthesize fbLikeWebView = _fbLikeWebView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Add this code for FbLike Webview

    self.fbLikeWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100.0, 50.0, 55.0, 70.0)];
    _fbLikeWebView.opaque = NO;
    _fbLikeWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _fbLikeWebView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_fbLikeWebView];

    for (UIScrollView *subview in _fbLikeWebView.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            subview.scrollEnabled = NO;
            subview.bounces = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

then in ViewWillAppear method call the enbeddFBLikeButton Method to add the fbLike button wigdet on web view:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self embedFBLikeButton];
    [_fbLikeWebView reload];
}

-(void)embedFBLikeButton
{
    NSString *facebookUrl =  //here paste the url you get from fb developer link above;

    [self.fbLikeWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookUrl]]];
}
```

You conform to UIWebViewDelegate now its turn to defining th edelegate method here:

```
#pragma mark - WebView Delgate Methods

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.lastPathComponent isEqualToString:@"login.php"])
    {
        [self login];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [_fbLikeWebView stopLoading];
}
```

This method for login the user to facebook Account:

```
- (void)login
{
    [FBSession setActiveSession: [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"publish_actions", @"publish_stream", @"user_photos"]]];

    [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior: FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        switch (status) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                // call the legacy session delegate
                //Now the session is open do corresponding UI changes
                if (session.isOpen) {
                    FBRequest *me = [FBRequest requestForMe];

                    [me startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                      NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                        if (!my) {
                            NSLog(@"Facebook error:\n%@", error.description);
                            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Error"
                                                        message: @"Facebook Login error."
                                                       delegate: self
                                              cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil, nil] show];
                            return;
                        }
                    }];

                    [_fbLikeWebView reload];

                    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @""
                                                message: @"Successfully Login. Please click on like button"
                                               delegate: self
                                      cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil, nil] show];
                }
                break;
            case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            {
                [_fbLikeWebView reload];
            }
                break;
            default:
                break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
        }
    }];
}
```

Enjoy Coding!!!